# soapUI: How to test web services behind WebSEAL?

Tags: soapui, tivoli, webseal

I have web service installed on application server. Security and SSO provides by placing this server behind WebSEAL and with using TAM. How I can test this service with helps of soapUI?
I always get WebSEAL login FORM.

Probably I need to turn something on inside soapUI to test stateful services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you need to feed in the same HTTP authentication headers which webSEAL sends when it sends the authenticated user request to the server. For example the PDCookie, iv-creds etc.

Comment: webseal send 401, can you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Depend how your webseal do the autentication, With a EAI, whit authentication form, etc. But in general, first you need be authenticated(HTTP Request with login), and second maintain de session with de cookie send from webseal. This article help you to setup the option to mantainde session and do several SOAP request then.

Basically you need to set in your test case options the "Mantain HTTP Session"

[Maintain HTTP Session](http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/form-based-authentication.html?_ga=1.185617196.4664730.1441068827)

Answer (score 0):

Postman <> Interceptor Integration:
https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290

The Interceptor is a very useful part of the Postman workflow - making API calls in the context of the browser’s session.